# How select row by it's number in MySql?

Tags: mysql, row, row-number

After modifying column MySql report an error:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable MODIFY mycolumn DECIMAL(9,4)
[2016-05-31 15:43:03] [22001][1264] Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'mycolumn' at row 33934497
```

The question is How to select row with number 33934497?

**Important notes**

As I understand MySql attach a row number to every row in the table. So there is must be a way select by this number. A `LIMIT` clause is not a case because it limit already selected rows, e.g. rows in select, not in table. Also the order during `select` and `modify` statement can be different, so using `LIMIT` is not a solution.

**UPDATED**

Information about min and max values in table:

`select Max(mycolumn) from MyTable` = -333240.0000

`select Min(mycolumn) from MyTable` = 1000000.0000

Do `1000000` and `-333240` fits to `DECIMAL(9,4)`?

Comment: Do you want to `SELECT`? This is an `ALTER TABLE` request. Any row identifiers MySQL has are never exposed deliberately. Your question here is really confused. What are you getting at?

Comment: How is it that you understand that MySQL "attach a row number to every row in the table"? When a row in the middle of table is deleted, does MySQL also automatically change the row number attached to all subsequent rows? Does the order of the rows in the table influence this row number that MySQL supposedly attaches? **NO.** It doesn't happen.  MySQL does *not* attach a row number to every row in the table.

Comment: Ok, suppose it does not attach a row number, in that case what does it mean by `at row 33934497`? If it report about error with "some number" for 1 row there must be a way to such row, no?

Comment: You don't want row 33934497. What you want is to identify the rows in the table that have a value stored in `mycolumn` that is out-of-range for `DECIMAL(9,4)`. We don't know the datatype of the (unfortunately named) `mycolumn`, I'd start with finding the highest and lowest values in mycolumn. Assuming that you want at most four digits following the decimal point, if the column is not currently DECIMAL datatype, I'd do the conversion and get max/min: `SELECT MAX(CONVERT(t.mycolumn,DECIMAL(65,4))) AS hval, MIN(CONVERT(t.mycolumn,DECIMAL(65,4))) AS lval FROM MyTable t`

Comment: ... to get all of the rows where the value of mycolumn would be out-of-range for DECIMAL(9,4)...  I would **`SELECT t.* FROM MyTable t WHERE CONVERT(t.mycolumn,DECIMAL(65,4) > 99999.9999 OR CONVERT(t.mycolumn,DECIMAL(65,4) < -99999.9999`**.  (The row identifed in the error from the ALTER TABLE statement will likely be one of the rows returned. It's also possible that this will return several rows.) I suspect you were meaning to specify `DECIMAL(13,4)` ... but that's just a guess. Not enough information provided about what you are *really* trying to accomplish... i.e. what the real problem is.

Comment: Question was updated, infromation about min and max values was provided. Could you please consult about max and min possible values for `DECIMAL(9,4)`, because initially I expect `9` digits "before" comma and `4` after.

Comment: To get nine digits before the decimal point and four after... you would need to specify datatype as **`DECIMAL(13,4)`**. That specifies a total of 13 decimal digits. Four of those digits are *after* the decimal point, leaving nine digits *before* the decimal point.   Reference:  [**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

If your current column type is `INT` and you are trying to switch to `DECIMAL(9,4)` I would select all records which contain values greater than 5 digits (9-4) which is 99999.

So just

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn>99999
```

Comment: And negative values could be out of range as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
 ...
OFFSET 33934496
LIMIT 1
```

OFFSET - skips n rows
notice that it uses your ORDER BY